# How to override Meta ordering attr from a Third-party app?

Tags: python, django

I'm using the [django-photologue](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-photologue) third-party app and I would like to override de Meta ordering attr.

More specificly the ordering attr from class [Gallery](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-photologue/blob/master/photologue/models.py).

Ty

Comment: I have not tried this, but I would guess: `Gallery.Meta.ordering = ('-created_date', )` in some `models.py` file at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The settings in the inner `Meta` class are available through the `_meta` attribute:

```
# mind the trailing comma, this should be a tuple
Gallery._meta.ordering = ('-create_date', )
```

Note that if you set the ordering to a non-existing field, trying to execute a query will raise a `FieldError`.